# usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-v VIDEO] [-i IMAGE] [-c CAMERA] [-o OUTPUT]

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to execute the `argparser` and the error is:

> usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] [-v VIDEO] [-i IMAGE] [-c CAMERA]
> [-o OUTPUT]
> ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /root/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/kernel-6bea2aa0-717c-4cb5-8793-534ee75b255f.json
> An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback.
> SystemExit: 2*

My `argparser` code :

```py
def argsParser():
    arg_parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    arg_parse.add_argument("-v", "--video", default=None, help="path to Video File ")
    arg_parse.add_argument("-i", "--image", default=None, help="path to Image File ")
    arg_parse.add_argument("-c", "--camera", default=False, help="Set True if you want to use the camera.")
    arg_parse.add_argument("-o", "--output", type=str, help="path to optional output video file")
    args = vars(arg_parse.parse_args())
    arg_parse.add_argument('-f')
    
    return args

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOGCV = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    HOGCV.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())

    args = argsParser()
    humanDetector(args)`
```

Could you help me what should I do? (btw I'm using google collaborator)

Comment: Poor title; you may want to write a more descriptive one. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```
def argsParser():
    arg_parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    arg_parse.add_argument("-v", "--video", default=None, help="path to       Video File ")
    arg_parse.add_argument("-i", "--image", default=None, help="path to Image File ")
    arg_parse.add_argument("-c", "--camera", default=True, help="Set true if you want to use the camera.")
    arg_parse.add_argument("-o", "--output", type=str, help="path to optional output video file")
    args = vars(arg_parse.parse_args())

    return args



if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOGCV = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    HOGCV.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
    args = argsParser()
    humanDetector(args)
```

This should give you the answer you are looking for, if anything i think it was a formating error

Answer (score 0):

You were so close. You just need to put "arg_parse.add_argument('-f')" line before "args = vars(arg_parse.parse_args())" ( This is the reason you are getting 'SystemExit: 2' error ):

Edit your argsParser like this:

```
def argsParser():
  arg_parse = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  arg_parse.add_argument("-v", "--video", default='your_video_path', help="path to Video File ")
  arg_parse.add_argument("-i", "--image", default='your_image_path', help="path to Image File ")
  arg_parse.add_argument("-c", "--camera", default='True/False', help="Set True if you want to use the camera.")
  arg_parse.add_argument("-o", "--output", type=str, default='your_output_path', help="path to optional output video file")
  arg_parse.add_argument("-f", required=False)

  args = vars(arg_parse.parse_args())

  return args
```

Now yoy can call:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOGCV = cv2.HOGDescriptor()
    HOGCV.setSVMDetector(cv2.HOGDescriptor_getDefaultPeopleDetector())
    args = argsParser()
    humanDetector(args)
```